# Is it possible to make a method (handler) receive messages from more than one inbound channels in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-cloud-stream

Assume I have this definition for `Sink` Interface

```java
public interface Sink {
  @Input("input")
  SubscribableChannel input();

  @Input("anotherInput")
  SubscribableChannel anotherInput();
}
```

and the following controller is bound to RabbitMQ (all set correctly according to *Spring Cloud Stream Binder Rabbit*)

```java
@Controller
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class InputMessageController {

    @StreamListener("input")
    public void handle(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received from input: " + message);
    }

    @StreamListener("anotherInput")
    public void handleOther(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received from another input: " + message);
    }
```

Although it works, but it's bad code because of duplicates etc.

I'd like to habe one handler in this controller which listens, in another word subscribes to both channels in `Sink` Interface and handles both of them based on some conditions for example. So far I couldn't figure it out with standard `@StreamListener` annotation, since it apparently does not accept an array of String (channel names)

My goal is sth like this:

```java
@Controller
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class InputMessageController {

    @StreamListener("input", "anotherInput")
    public void handle(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received " + message + "from " +
                   ((/*some condition*/) ? "1st" : "2nd") + " input");
    }
```

I'd appreciate any idea to solve it clean or explanation about Spring Cloud Stream API!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your class with Rabbitlistener and declare your queues as argument, then annotate a method with Rabbithandler. This method receives inputs for all declared queues.

```
@Controller
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
@RabbitListener(queues = {"input", "anotherInput"})
public class InputMessageController {

    @RabbitHandler
    public void handle(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received " + message + "from " +
                   ((/*some condition*/) ? "1st" : "2nd") + " input");
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a class level `@RabbitListener`, you can do the same on a method. However, this doesn't answer the question; he is using `@StreamListener` not `@RabbitListener`.

Comment: @GaryRussell check my comment under your answer… Will `@StreamListener` support multiple inbounding channels anytime in the future releases or it is intentionally so? btw I assume that this solution is correct… I have to test it first!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way do do it is like this

```java
    @StreamListener("input")
    public void handle(String message) {
        actualListener(message);
    }

    @StreamListener("anotherInput")
    public void handleOther(String message) {
        actualListener(message);
    }

    public void actualListener(String message) {
        ...
    }
```

**EDIT**

Actually, there is a better solution; you can specify multieple destinations for the binding...

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=dest1,dest2
```

By default, you will get a different listener container for each destination; if you set `multiplex` to `true`, you will get a single container that listens to both destinations (queues in the case of the rabbit binder).

Comment: thanks Gary. It's a smart primitive solution that puts a check mark by the DRY without changing what is given. But as i mentioned in my goal snippet at the end of the question, I'd like to tidy up my class, even visually and have no problem with using another interface/annotation… (or you wouldn't recommend it?)

Comment: Actually, there is a, perhaps, better solution; see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Isn't it too global? There's only one method in my app that needs it… not sure if changing manipulating application.properties from above is a good idea. I think the most clean solution would even be sending both sort of messages to one queue and filter 'em in one handler… no need to repeat method or use other interfaces…

Comment: It’s all about choice :)

Comment: does any advanced principle discourage the use of `@RabbitListener` instead of `@StreamListener` here, suppose i can't change pipelines and wouldn't change the global settings?

Comment: Not really, but `@RabbitListener` is a bit lower level. It doesn’t auto provision the broker. You have to either declare the queue, exchange and binding as beans or specify `@QueueBinding` properties on the `@RabbitListener` itself. But aside from that the functionality is similar.

Answer (score 1):

With just released Horsham.RELEASE you can make it even simpler using function based programming model.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleStreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleStreamApplication.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> sink() {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}
```

This will default to `sink-in-0` binding name. 
And then as Gary suggested use `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sink-in-0.destination=dest1,dest2` property.

As you can see with functional programming model your application is jus a plain boot app which requires no additional configuration or knowledge of the internals from the user.

You can read more ab out *functional* vs. *annotation-driven* and why we're moving away from the later [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified)